# Sums and integral with fractional part

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I'm stuck in this step on a proof:

> $$s \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \int_n^{n+1}x^{-s-1}dx=s\int_1^\infty
>  [x]x^{-s-1}dx$$

Any idea on how to prove it? Hints and suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interval $[n,n+1)$, $[x] = n$. Thus $n\int_n^{n+1} x^{-s-1}\, dx = \int_n^{n+1} nx^{-s-1}\, dx = \int_n^{n+1}[x]x^{-s-1}\, dx$. Thus

$$s\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n\int_n^{n+1}x^{-s-1}\, dx = s\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} [x]x^{-s-1}\, dx = \cdots$$